# How to convert a factor to numeric in a predefined order in R

Tags: r

I have a factor column, with three values: "b", "c" and "free".

I did

```
df$new_col = as.numeric (df$factor_col)
```

But it will convert "b" to 1, "c" to 2 and "free" to 3.

But I want to convert "free" to 0, "b" to 2 and "c" to 5. How can I do it in R?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try `as.numeric(as.character(factor(df$factor_col, levels=c('b', 'c', 'free'), labels=c(2, 5, 0))))`  Another option is `library(car); with(df, recode(factor_col, "'b'=2; 'c'=5; 'free'=0"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to call the 'factor' again and specify the `levels` and `labels` argument based on the custom order and change to `numeric` after converting to 'character' or through the `levels`

```
 df$new_col <- as.numeric(as.character(factor(df$factor_col,
               levels=c('b', 'c', 'free'), labels=c(2, 5, 0))))
```

Another option is `recode` from `library(car)`.  The output will be `factor` class.  If we need to convert to 'numeric', we can do this as in the earlier solution (`as.numeric(..`).

```
library(car)
df$new_col <- with(df, recode(factor_col, "'b'=2; 'c'=5; 'free'=0"))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(factor_col= c('b', 'c', 'b', 'free', 'c', 'free'))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
f <- factor(c("b", "c", "c", "free", "b", "free"))
```

You can try renaming the factor levels,

```
levels(f)[levels(f)=="b"] <- 2
levels(f)[levels(f)=="c"] <- 5
levels(f)[levels(f)=="free"] <- 0
> f
#[1] 2 5 5 0 2 0
#Levels: 2 5 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach to create the new column:

```
# an example data frame
f <- data.frame(factor_col = c("b", "c", "free"))  

# create new_col    
f <- transform(f, new_col = (factor_col == "b") * 2 + (factor_col == "c") * 5)
```

The result (`f`):

```
  factor_col new_col
1          b       2
2          c       5
3       free       0
```